# To find a basis for the given subspace of $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is to find a basis for the given subspace of $R^4$:

All vectors that are perpendicular to $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(1,0,1,1)$

How should I proceed?Should I have to find a vector perpendicular to both of the given vectors and go further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an arbitrary vector $(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^4$. Work out $(x,y,z,w)\cdot(1,1,0,0)$ and $(x,y,z,w)\cdot(1,0,1,1)$.

$(x,y,z,w)$ is in your subspace if and only if both of these dot products are zero.

This gives the equations $x+y=0$ and $x+z+w=0$. So we can write $y=-x$ and $w=-x-z$. Therefore, a generic point in the subspace can be written $(x,-x,z,-x-z)$.

$$(x,-x,z,-x-z)=x(1,-1,0,-1)+z(0,0,1,-1)\,.$$
So what do you think the basis is?